# How to Get the Value Held Within a Custom Element in a <div>

Tags: javascript, html

Hopefully, this is fairly straight forward. From within JavaScript code, how do you get the value of 1 from the attribute dataID within the div element below:

```
<div class="widget" dataID="1"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the attribute value like this:

```
var value = element.getAttribute('dataID');
```

Before that, you need to get the reference to the element. You can get it by adding id to the element:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element-id');
```

, or by class:

```
var elements = documents.getElementsByClassName('widget');
Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    var value = element.getAttribute('dataID');
    //...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation according to the div element ID and getting the value within the attribute or class.

Answer (score 1):

Just read an attribute:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".widget").getAttribute("dataID"))
```

```html
<div class="widget" dataID="1"></div>
```

Or add the dash and use dataset:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".widget").dataset.id)
```

```html
<div class="widget" data-id="1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer was useful as well.